# Point root domain to one server and all sub-domains to another server

Tags: subdomain, godaddy, tomcat6, rackspace, wildcard-subdomain

I have a requirement where I want to point my root domain i.e

www.abc.com or abc.com to one server (static website)

and *.abc.com to another server (application server)

I have bought domain from godaddy, I want godaddy to host my static website i.e

www.abc.com and abc.com.

I have a hosting account with rackspace so I want to point *.abc.com i.e. all

subdomains to my rackspace hosting.

My application will run on tomcat web server.

Any ideas :)

Answer (score 2):

Most domain registrars allow you to create [wildcard DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) entries. So you can have www.abc.com pointing to your web server and *.abc.com pointing somewhere else.

Comment: so you are saying i should do something like this.

abc.com A 1.2.3.4
*.abc.com A 7.8.9.10

Am I right ?

Comment: The basic GoDaddy domain manager does **not** allow wildcard CNAME entries. You will need to use a third party DNS provider and configure their servers as the authoritative ones for your domain.

Comment: I can use rackspace as a DNS provider but how do i configure GoDaddy servers to make rackspace DNS as the authoriatative ones.

Comment: I haven't used GoDaddy for a little while but I did setup wild card DNS on it. Try the advanced DNS editor. Also you don't want a CNAME, an A record is the correct type for this.